# Neural network for time series forecasting with an auxiliary data

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm

Lets say we have 2 data sets. First is the close price time series data set and we want to predict future values of it. The second is volumes of each price from the first data set and we do not want to predict on it but use this data to help predict future price values.

What kind of neural networks is suitable for this task?

In my sight this may be an LSTM with some changes.

Advise me please.

Comment: Hello There! May I ask why you want to use NN ? is your goal to do accurate predictions, or to just find a use for neural networks ?
Depending on your feedback, we might recommend various algorithms for forecasting, that are not necessarily based on a neural network architecture. cheers!

Comment: You can use RNN architectures like LSTM, and GRU. RNNs take input vectors in each time step, so you can add your extra data to input vector. Your input shape will be batch_size x sequence length x num_of_features.

Comment: @tkarahan You should convert your comment to a formal answer.

Comment: @10xAI I posted content of my comment as an answer.

Comment: Hello @Wajdi! I believe that NN is more perspective but you have intrigued me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RNN architectures like LSTM, and GRU. RNNs take input vectors in each time step, so you can add your extra data to input vector. Your input shape will be batch_size x sequence length x num_of_features.

Comment: What if I have many-to-many with main sequence discrete valued [+1, 0 ,-1]?